# Rails 5 Model not inheriting the parent's methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, abstract-class, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the `ApplicationRecord` model as follows:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def hello_world
    return "helllloo"
  end
end
```

and I have `Instance` model as follows:

```
class Instance < ApplicationRecord

end
```

Then I have the controller trying to run the `hello_world`, but it's throwing the following error saying `hello_world` method is not available.

**Controller**

```
class InstancesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_instance, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /instances
  def index
    @instances = Instance.all
    return render(:json => {:instances => @instances, :hi_message => Instance.hello_world})
  end
end
```

**Error**

```
{
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "#<NoMethodError: undefined method `hello_world' for #<Class:0x00000009b3d4a0>>",
  "traces": {
    "Application Trace": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "trace": "app/controllers/instances_controller.rb:7:in `index'"
      }
    ],.....
```

Any idea why it's not inheriting the methods?

**Note: ** I am running the app in API mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One point to mention here is `hello_world` is instance method and you are calling it on a class instead of instance

**Solution 1:**

Change the method to class method

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def self.hello_world
    return "helllloo"
  end
end
```

and

```
Instance.hello_world
#=> "helllloo"
```

**Solution 2:**

Call the method on instance

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def hello_world
    return "helllloo"
  end
end
```

and

```
Instance.new.hello_world
#=> "helllloo"

# OR

instance = Instance.new
instance.hello_world
#=> "helllloo"
```